# MVC DropDown Tree select?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, treeview, drop-down-menu, tree

**Hi!**

Im looking for a DropDown Tree Select. I have looked at this [Tree control](http://code.google.com/p/dynatree/), but im not sure how to combind this with a dropdown button where the selected values are shown in the button when not expanded?

**BestRegards**
SowJim

Edit : Dropdown tree looks somthing like this : [image]